# Using a single letter like Y or N and their small letter counterparts from an input function in an if and elif statement

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to use single letters like "Y or y" and "N or n" from an input function in and if and elif statement:

```
print("Main Breakfast Menu")
print("1. Pancakes")
print("2. Waffles")
print("3. Bacon & Eggs")
print("4. Omellette")
print("5. Oats")
print("6. Pizza Slice")
MainChoice = int(input("Select a Breakfast meal: "))

SideAns = input("Would you like a side to go with your meal? Y/N ") 
if (MainChoice == 1) and (SideAns == Y):
print("Sides")
print("1. Extra Bacon")
print("2. Switch Bacon for Turkey Bacon")
print("3. Toast")
print("4. Syrup for pancakes or waffles")
print("5. Drinks")
```

This block of code beneath is where it gives errors.
The compiler states an input like "Y" is not defined, when I pass of "y" or "n" it states the same.

```
if (MainChoice == 1) and SideAns( == Y):
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it could be helpful to add checks if the input is valid; just try converting some letters to integer... see e.g. [here](https://www.101computing.net/number-only/)

Comment: Right now, you're checking whether `SideAns` equals the variable `Y`. However, a variable with the name Y is not defined. To check whether your `SideAns` equals the string Y, you'll have to write `SideAns == "Y"`.

Comment: Thank you both for your input and the links. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the quotes and indentation.

```
if (MainChoice == 1) and (SideAns == "Y"):
    print("Sides")
```

You can even accept both, lowercase and uppercase with :

```
if (MainChoice == 1) and (SideAns.upper() == "Y"):
    print("Sides")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was also searching on how to accept both upper case and lower case input. You answered two questions of mine in one shot. Thank you so much